# Probability a natural number of the form $m^2 - n^2$ can be exactly factored as the product of $2$ primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, semiprimes

> Let $P$ be the probability that two integers where $m>1$is a fixed positive integer and $n$ is a randomly chosen such than $ m> n \geq 0 $? What is the probability $m^2 -n^2$ and be factored into $2$ factors.

I think the probability is at least $P(m^2 -n^2 = p_i p_j) \geq \frac{1}{m}$, where $p_i$ and $p_j$ are arbitrary primes.

Comment: You have to give a procedure for picking such a number, since there is no uniform probability on natural numbers. Or you could give a density, which is different from probability. 
The set of numbers of the form $n^2-m^2$ is all odd numbers, plus all multiples of $4.$

Comment: You can’t pick $m$ first all with equal probability. That’s what it means that “there is no uniform probability on the natural numbers.”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I choose an $m$ (this should be clearer). So basically if I have $m=3$. Then I have $1/3$ rd chance of the following: $m^2$, $m^2 - 1^2$ , $m^2 -2^2$   being factorable into $p_i p_j$. Here the answer is $m^2 = 3^2$

Comment: Perhaps you can rephrase your question like this: let $I(k)$ be the probability that two integers $m,n$ randomly chosen from $[1,k]$ are such that $|m^2 - n^2|$ can be factored as the product of exactly two primes, then what is $\lim I(k)$?

Comment: Perhaps we should start by considering  $m$ to be a fixed positive integer?

Comment: @DescartesBeforetheHorse I think I'll take hardmath suggestion instead

Comment: Note you're just asking whether $m-n$ and $m+n$ are both primes.  It is unlikely there is a way to efficiently compute this for a fixed $m$, but some sort of asymptotic expression can probably be massaged out of the prime number theorem.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I'll settle for the asymptotic expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm interpreting the question as: "For a fixed $m$, how many $0\le n<m$ have the property that $n-m$ and $n+m$ are both prime?" (Note that this is a little bit wrong for $n=m-1$, but never mind.)

This is exactly the same as asking how many representations $2m$ has as the sum of two primes. In other words, this is the Goldbach conjecture in disguise.

So we would love to prove (but currently can't) that this number of representations is positive for all $m\ge2$.

There is also a [conjectured asymptotic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#Heuristic_justification), as a function of $m$, for the number of such representations.

Answer (score 1):

According to OEIS entry [A001358](https://oeis.org/A001358), the $n$th semiprime is asymptotically equal to $n \log(n) / \log ( \log (n))$.

This means the "probability" that a number $n$ is semiprime is asymptotically equal to $\log (\log (n))/ \log(n)$.

Therefore the probability that $m^2-n^2$ is semiprime for any natual $m, n$ is $\log (\log (m^2-n^2))/ \log(m^2-n^2)$.

Comment: The first formula assumes that we have a completly random n with no information about the factorization of n.
But $m^2-n^2$ can already be trivialy factored.

Comment: @MichaelStocker I agree but I would guess that this is the best approximate we can get for the probability right now